# Denwer apache restart

Tags: apache, restart

I often restart apache during development e.g. for doggling on/off x-debug, update Doctrine cache...

Uppon installation [Denwer](http://www.denwer.ru/) puts 3 shortcuts on desktop `Start Denwer`, `Stop Denwer` and `Restart Denwer`. Those are pointed to appropriate .exe files. However `Restart Denwer` restarts all services including MySQL, hosts file, mail daemon which takes 10 sec+.

How can I restart apache only?

Answer (score 0):

apache-restart.bat

```
cd /d z:\denwer\scripts\init.d
z:\usr\local\miniperl\miniperl.exe apache.pl restart
```